# How do I enable button while there is a string in my textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox and a button in form2. When an item is clicked in form1, form2 appears. I would like to keep the button in form2 disabled while the textbox is empty, but when user starts typing, I'd like to enable the button.

I have tried using an if in my constructor after the initialisecomponent() like so, but it does not work:

```
if(textbox1.text != "")
{
   btnOne.Enabled = true;
}
```

I have also tried calling a method called `checkText()` after the initialise component which uses a do-while loop to check like:

```
do{
    btnOne.Enabled = true
  }
 while(textbox1.text != "");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to make a comment about your do while loop. This is very bad as it will freeze up the UI thread

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use an event. Check out the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event for the `TextBox` control.

Basically you will want something like this:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnOne.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text);
}
```

If you are using Visual Studio you can do the following to add the event code.

- Open designer view
- Select the TextBox control
- View the "Events" window
- Find the "TextChanged" event
- Double-click the value space, and the code will be added automatically for you to work with

---

**Note**: This approach will require the user to "lose focus" on the `TextBox` control before the event fires. If you want an as-you-type solution then check out the [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) event instead

@Asif has made a good point regarding checking for whitespace characters too. This is your call on what is valid, but if you do not want to allow whitespace value to be used then you can use the [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method instead - however, this requires you to be using .Net Framework 4.0 or higher

Comment: @ifelabolz: It's called by the `TextBox` control, but the event (assuming you follow my instructions) will be registered within the designer.cs file. I suggest you do some research on events, you don't seem familiar with them, but you will want to use them quite often as you develop

Comment: yeah, i understand whats happening with the events, i initially thought i had to call it in the code, this was before you added the control to ur answer, thanks i got it working now.

Comment: @ifelabolz: Well... nothing says thanks better than accepting somebody else's answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Textbox changed event in windows form

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't allow white spaces as a valid input then you should use  `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

```
textbox1.TextChanged += (sender, e)
{
    btnOne.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text);
};
```

Comment: That is debatable... maybe whitespace is valid input, unlikely I know but I don't think you should be saying one is better than the other

Comment: its possible but not probable.

Comment: both answers are valid, whitespaces are not valid in this case, thanks @Asif