# How to disable the submit button until a textbox is not empty in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, disabled-control

Can you teach me how to disable a button until all textboxes are not empty?
In my design form `login`, I have 2 textboxes and 2 buttons.
I want to disable the buttons until both textboxes are not empty.

Here is my code in a `c#` Windows application form:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ADMIN-\MSSQLSERVERR;Initial Catalog=Admin;Integrated Security=True");
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select USN From Admin where USN ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);


        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Admin_Panel aa = new Admin_Panel(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            aa.Show();
        }

        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your username and password");
            textBox1.SelectAll();
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select USN From Admin where USN ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);


        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Student aa = new Student(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            aa.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your username and password");
            textBox1.SelectAll();
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }


        button2.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);

    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = true;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);


    }
```

I also tried this

```
button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);
```

... but when I had already put Username and Password in the textboxes, the 2 buttons were not enabled.

Comment: You mean you want to enable buttons only if username and password is entered in textbox is it?

Comment: kinda, i want to enable when the two textbox is filled
in my code button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);
if the textbox is empty it will disable the buttons
but when i filled the two textbox the buttons is still disable i dont know how to code for enable once the textbox is not empty @VijayKumbhoje

Comment: i dont know how to put/use if else statement in my codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# winsform How do i enable button while there is a string in my textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085079/c-sharp-winsform-how-do-i-enable-button-while-there-is-a-string-in-my-textbox)

Answer (score 3):

First set your buttons.Enabled property to false. Then add a TextChanged-Handler for both TextBoxes, where you check if both TextBoxes contain something.

The code of the handlers could look like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setButtonVisibility();
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setButtonVisibility();
}

private void setButtonVisibility()
{
    if ((textBox1.Text != String.Empty) && (textBox2.Text != String.Empty))
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would refactor this as `textBox1_TextChanged` and `textBox2_TextChanged` have the same exact body.  Encourage good practices for beginners

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting this right: do you think it would be better to delete the code of the second handler, because it's the same like the code of the first handler? :)

Comment: as @B. Clay Shayton did in his answer, extract into a single method, and call that method in the body of your event handlers.  I'll make an edit to yours to show you

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to monitor changes to the textboxes, in their Changed event, like:

```
private void textbox1_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConditionallyEnableSubmitButton();
}

private void textbox2_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConditionallyEnableSubmitButton();
}

private void ConditionallyEnableSubmitButton()
{
    button1.Enabled = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) ||   
                       !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text));
}
```

Hint at no extra charge: give any control that you are going to reference programmatically a recognizable name, such as "btnSubmit", "txtbxUsername", "txtbxPwd" etc.

You could do a lot worse than to read Steve McConnell's "Code Complete" for this and many other nudges toward good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableButton();
}

private void textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableButton();
}

private void  EnableButton()
{
    if(textbox1.Text == "" || textbox2.Text == "")
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```